# How to select where two rows in same column has same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Note: Using Postgres 
I tried for hours and read many posts but still can not figure out how to make this query.

**I have two tables**

**chat table**

| id | is_group_chat |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | false |
| 2 | false |

**user_chat table (linked with user table)**

| chat_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |

I need to select chat which is between two user only.

I have achieved this

```
select c.id as c_id, c.chat_name as chat_name, c.created_at as created_at
from chats c 
left join user_chats uc on uc.chat_id = c.id 
where c.is_group_chat = false 
and uc.user_id = '39438219-1488-4e6f-820a-2ba16ba12e01'
intersect 
select c.id as c_id, c.chat_name as chat_name, c.created_at as created_at
from chats c 
left join user_chats uc on uc.chat_id = c.id 
where c.is_group_chat = false 
and uc.user_id = '16c1beb9-687a-45b3-8d2b-88c71a681168';
```

As you can see I needed to write almost same query two times is there any better way to do this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL, please do not tag other brands of database that you are not using. It doesn't help you get better answers.

Comment: Tip on formatting tables in Stack Overflow markdown: Leave a blank line before and after the table, don't use `<br>`.

Comment: Yes @BillKarwin I have tagged mysql because query is same in both but you have removed mysql tag let it go this way now, no worries

Comment: It's also the same query in SQLite, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, IBM DB2, and Informix. Just because your current query appears similar in different implementations of SQL, doesn't necessarily mean that the solution to your question will be the same. The best solution for PostgreSQL might be a PostgreSQL-specific feature. The best solution for MySQL might be a MySQL-specific feature. And so on. If you get a solution from someone who sees the MySQL tag, they might give a solution that works only in MySQL, and that just wastes their time and your time.

Comment: "between two user only" Can you clarify this? It can be interpreted a few ways - Chats that are between this users and ONLY these users. So a group chat with 3 users 39438219-1488-4e6f-820a-2ba16ba12e01, 16c1beb9-687a-45b3-8d2b-88c71a681168, and 123-123-123 would be excluded. Because 123-123-123 is crashing the party. Or, this could be interpreted that you want chats that contain at least these users. In which case 123-123-123 wouldn't cause it to be excluded. This is important because it determines whether it's a simple filter or a relational division problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample query, you appear to be only interested in specific users. This is based on that appearance.

Use `HAVING` clause. Also, since you want to query user ids, then you INNER JOIN (not left join) to user_chat.

```
create table chats (
  id integer, 
  chat_name varchar(20), 
  is_group_chat varchar(10), 
  create_at date
  );
  
insert into chats values 
(1, 'fruit', 'false', '2023-10-01'), 
(2, 'fruit', 'false', '2023-10-02'), 
(3, 'cars', 'true', '2023-10-03');

create table user_chats (
  chat_id integer, 
  user_id integer
  );
  
insert into user_chats values 
(1, 1), 
(1, 2), 
(2, 1), 
(2, 3), 
(3, 4), 
(3, 2);
```

---

```
select 
 c.id as chat_id, 
 c.chat_name, 
 c.create_at
from chats c
join user_chats uc
  on c.id = uc.chat_id
where c.is_group_chat = 'false'
  and uc.user_id in (1, 2)
group by 1,2,3
having count(distinct uc.user_id) = 2;
```

| chat_id | chat_name | create_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fruit | 2023-10-01T00:00:00.000Z |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQaHEoFBJ68fmZLvU9rbdi/0)

Comment: Thank you so much and it is working, Want to know how `group by 1,2,3` is working ): . Thanks again.

Comment: That's an ordinal way to say `group by id, chat_name, create_at` (ie, referencing the column number). Just a shorter way to write code in Postgres and several other DBMS. If this answer is helpful then please consider marking the Accept flag.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply join the table, group the rows by the chat id, and then count them.

```
WITH TwoUserChats AS (
    SELECT c.id as chat_id
    FROM chats c INNER JOIN
        user_chats uc ON uc.chat_id = c.id 
    WHERE c.is_group_chat = false 
        AND c.id IN 
          (
            '39438219-1488-4e6f-820a-2ba16ba12e01', 
            '16c1beb9-687a-45b3-8d2b-88c71a681168'
          )
    GROUP BY c.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)

SELECT DISTINCT
     c.id AS c_id  
    ,c.chat_name AS chat_name 
    ,c.created_at AS created_at
FROM chats c INNER JOIN 
    TwoPersonChats ON c.id = TwoPersonChats.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include chats that involved other users then just remove `count()` filter:

```
select * from chats where is_group_chat = 'false' and chat_id in (
    select chat_id
    from user_chat
    group by chat_id
    having min(chat_id) = 'X' and max(chat_id) = 'Y' and count(chat_id) = 2
);
```

If you possibly need to check more than two user ids (or if you just want to use this version with two ids):

```
select * from chats where is_group_chat = 'false' and chat_id in (
    select chat_id
    from user_chat
    group by chat_id
    having count(case when chat_id in ('X', 'Y', ...) then 1 end) = N
);
```